# How to find un-used IP addresses in network?

Tags: android, network-protocols

Anyone have idea how can find available IP addresses in a network using any protocol?

UDP broadcasting is one way. But in this case every one should have a listener app?

Please suggest if have any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send ICMP pings to the broadcast network address. For example, if your interface IP is in the 192.168.0.0/24 network, you would send pings to 192.168.0.255 -

```
[22:45:54 jmac:~]$ ping 192.168.0.255
PING 192.168.0.255 (192.168.0.255): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.159 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=99.708 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.147 ms
```

However to send ICMP ping from an application, you'll need to open raw sockets & thus you'll need root permissions. The ping program on most OSes are setuid root programs, so they can be invoked by any user.

Comment: Thanks Jaidev , do u have any idea how to get root access problematically.

Comment: Since you tagged it as android, I believe on android you'll actually have to do something like - runtime.exec("su");.


On normal UNIXes, you'll have to do setuid (0) in your program. The program binary should be owned by root and have the setuid bit set. 
So you'll need to: chown root your_exe; setuid u+s your_exe;


Edit: This means that you already had root access. If you don't have root access, you can't gain in programmatically.

Comment: Ya, but you can try invoking the ping utility and parsing the response.